# Why do I get invalid characters when converting MS SQL Data to MYSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding

I'm writing a PHP script to import data into a MYSQL database from a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database.

The MSSQL Server is set with a collation of "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and the data in question is being stored in a column of the type "nchar".

My PHP web pages use

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

to indicate that they should be displayed with UTF-8 Character encoding.

I'm pulling the data from the MSSQL database using the sqlsrv PHP extension.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM [tArticle] WHERE [ID] = 6429';
$stmt = &sqlsrv_query($dbHandler, $sql);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) {
  // examples of what I've tried simply to display the data
  echo $row->Text1;
  echo utf8_encode($row->Text1);
  echo iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $row->Text1);
  echo iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $row->Text1);
}
```

Forget about inserting the data into the MYSQL database for now.  I can't get the string to display properly in my PHP page.  From the examples in my listing:

```
echo $row->Text1
```

is rendered by my browser as an obviously invalid character:  "Lucy�s"

all of the examples following that one are rendered as blanks:  "Lucys"

It looks like a character set mismatch problem to me but how can I get this data to display properly from the MS SQL database (without changing my web-page encoding)?  If I can figure that out I can probably work out the storing it in the MYSQL database part.

Comment: I haven't worked with sqlsrv but you may need to set its connection encoding upon connecting to the database. The equivalent of running `SET NAMES utf8` under mysql after connecting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the strings in the source database are encoded in UTF-8, you should use `utf8_decode`, not `utf8_encode`.

But they're probably encoded in some Latin or "Western" [Windows code page](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/codepages.html#msftwindows). So I would try `iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $row->Text1);`, for example.

Another alternative is to run a SQL query that explicitly sets a known encoding. For example, according to the [Windows Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188046.aspx) documentation, this query would use code page 1252 to encode field Text1:  `SELECT Text1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS FROM ...`.

Comment: iconv with "CP1252" did the trick which is odd to me since the MS documentation on the "nchar" field claims that it's a unicode field encoded with UCS-2 character set. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 7):

try this command it's working for me :

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBName", "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... you just saved my day!